# Undefined variable after wrapped include in PHP

Tags: php

I'm using PHP for web development. I'm using the following function to wrap the `include` of a view:

```
<?php
function render($templateFile) {
    $templateDir = 'views/';
    if (file_exists($templateDir . $templateFile)) {
        include $templateDir . $templateFile;
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Template '{$templateFile}' couldn't be found " .
           "in '{$templateDir}'");
    }
}
?>
```

Although this seems right to me, there is a really unexpected behavior: when I define a variable to something (e.g. an array) and use `render` for including a view that uses that variable, I get an `undefined variable` error. But when I explicitely use `include` there is **no error at all** and things are just fine.

This is the script that calls `render`:

```
<?php
include 'lib/render.php'; // Includes the function above.

$names = array('Trevor', 'Michael', 'Franklin');

render('names.html'); // Error, but "include 'views/names.html'" works fine.
?>
```

And this is the file that uses the `$names` variable:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Names</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ol>
    <?php foreach ($names as $name): ?>
      <li><?php echo $name; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

Help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: wouldn't it error anyway if you pass an array to the function, since you're not iterating through the array in your function.

Comment: Try to avoid using `include` and prefer `include_once`, although that will only give a warning. I think it is best practise (ymm) to always use `require_once` so that you will know immediately if the referenced file cannot be accessed.

Comment: $templatePath =  $templateDir . $templateFile;
include $templatePath;

Comment: @volkinc Whether you post it as an answer or as a comment, it's still not necessary to do it that way (it works just fine as is), and it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Mawg You don't want to `include_once` in this case.  What if you want to render the view template more than once in the execution of the script?  For example, if the view is a widget that is output three times on a page.

Comment: @Cully Larson, you are right. this is a scope problem

Comment: Sorry, what am I missing? Render.php declares a function. It should be included once (only) in each individual PHP file that wants to call the function. It you include it several times in one file then you will redeclare an existing function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from the PHP documentation on the include function (c.f. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable
> scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available
> at that line in the calling file will be available within the called
> file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes
> defined in the included file have the global scope.

And also:

> If the include occurs inside a function within the calling file, then
> all of the code contained in the called file will behave as though it
> had been defined inside that function. So, it will follow the variable
> scope of that function.

So, if your `render` function can't access `$names`, then neither can your included file.

A possible solution would be to pass the parameters you want to be able to access in your view template, to your `render` function.  So, something like this:

```
function render($templateFile, $params=array()) {
    $templateDir = 'views/';
    if (file_exists($templateDir . $templateFile)) {
        include $templateDir . $templateFile;
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Template '{$templateFile}' couldn't be found " .
           "in '{$templateDir}'");
    }
}
```

Then, pass them like this:

```
$names = array('Trevor', 'Michael', 'Franklin');

render('names.html', array("names" => $names));
```

And use them in your view template like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Names</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ol>
    <?php foreach ($params['names'] as $name): ?>
      <li><?php echo $name; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

There are probably better solutions to this, like putting your `render` function into a `View` class.  Then you can call the `View` class function from inside your template file, and access parameters that way instead of just assuming there will be a `$params` variable in the view templates scope.  But, this is the simplest solution.

Comment: I feel kinda awful because reading the docs more carefully could've save me the error, but thank you a lot anyways. I'm definitely marking this as the right answer. As for the approach in rendering the views I know that encapsulating in a class is way better, but this is a code that's intended to help with development of students in a software engineering course focusing on structured programming (no OO yet) in which I'm TA.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, when you include the file directly using `include 'views/names.html'` the variable `$name` remains in the same files scope. Hence, it works. But when the include is done through the function, **the varibale `$name` remains out of scope inside the function**. So it doesn't work. For example, **declare `$names` as global** inside the function and it will work.

If you update the function like below you will see `$names` variable works.

```
function render($templateFile) {

    global $names; // declares the global $names variable to use in the included files

    $templateDir = 'views/';
    if (file_exists($templateDir . $templateFile)) {
        include $templateDir . $templateFile;
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Template '{$templateFile}' couldn't be found " .
           "in '{$templateDir}'");
    }
}
```